# "Cannot fully validate proxy" message with RequestFactory

Tags: android, requestfactory

While working on an AppEngine connected Android project, I occasionally have problems with RequestFactory validation, such as the following warning I see in the error log:

> Cannot fully validate proxy since type foo is not available Add
>   @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") to dismiss.

This is usually fixed by edited some of the files in the project, saving, which forces a re-build, and presumably, a re-validation. And type "foo" has always been available, I don't know why it occasionally thinks it is not available.

I don't know how to force a re-validation, or what causes it to re-validate when I edit, but sometimes I can't get it to re-validate at all, like now.

Since this question is vague, I'm simply asking for some general direction on where to look to begin fixing this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignored the warning, did a bunch of saves to rebuild the project and continued on, as I have in the past, and the project is now working.